Should you compute the FID for the reconstructed images or for the image obtained from text?
I am trying to train a text to image model based on Muse. I am planning on how to evaluate the result and I realized there's something about the Frechet Inception Distance that I don't understand.
Muse (and my version of it) works rougly this way:

there's an encoder that represents an image using a number of tokens (lets say 64) where each token can take one of several possible values (say 8192)
there's a decoder that takes the 64 tokens and reconstructs the image based on them
the final component is a transformer that takes in text tokens, and generates image tokens that hopefully match the given text

The actual image generation, after training, goes like this:

you pass a piece of text to the transformer
the transformer generates the 64 image tokens
the tokens are passed to the decoder which turns them into an actual image

My question is, how do I compute the FID for such a model? I see $2$ ways to do it:

take the original images, pass them through the encoder and then reconstruct them. Compute the FID between the original images and the reconstructed images. This would only use the encoder and decoder.
take the image captions, use the entire model to generate images based on those captions, and then compute FID between the generated images and the original images.

The second option seems more reasonable to me, since it tests the entire model. I wasn't able to find anything online about this, and while I seem to doubt my intuition a lot less after I wrote this question, it would be helpful it somebody could confirm/infirm it. Thank you!
